# How do I improve performance of HTML list with over 3000 items built with handlebars.js?

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

I am building a webpage which takes a list of names and displays them in a scrolling list. There are on average, over 3000 names and new names are added on an ongoing basis.

The problem is that the size of the list is causing a performance hit on the page. I'd like to make the page faster and this is one of the things that I need to improve.

My thoughts are that there may be some way to use caching to store the list and update the cache when a new name is added. Or somehow, pre-build the list and then display the finished list when the page is requested using an iframe or something like that. I have no idea if these things will work, they are just on the edge of what I know about HTML, but these are paths I'm looking at currently.

What I've tried is the current solution of building the list using handlebars.js. This is the handlebars.js template I'm using.

```
<ul class="donor_list">
    {{#each Donors}}
        <li>{{Name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it slow because you are waiting for the query to return data or is it handlebars.js that is taking a long time to render?

Comment: It's slow based on PageSpeedInsights and other optimization tests. PageSpeedInsigts advises "Avoid an excessive DOM size. Browser engineers recommend pages contain fewer than ~1,500 DOM elements." My page currently has almost 2,500 DOM elements because of this UL.

Comment: I would suggest lazy loading then. Load 100 at a time and use an ajax request to fetch the next 100 as they scroll to the bottom of the page.